Understanding discrepancies between Etherscan deployed bytecode and locally compiled bytecode for smart contracts
I’m experiencing an issue when examining the bytecode of this smart contract 0x7c21C4Bbd63D05Fa9F788e38d14e18FC52E9557B.
After locating the contract on Etherscan and viewing the contract code in the “Contract” section (https://etherscan.io/address/0x7c21C4Bbd63D05Fa9F788e38d14e18FC52E9557B#code), I observed that there are two timestamp operations present. However, when I look at the EVM bytecode under the “Deployed Bytecode” section, I can’t find any opcode corresponding to the timestamp instruction. Conversely, when I check the ‘Contract Creation Code’, the timestamp opcode is present.
Additionally, when I compile the same contract locally using the SOLC compiler, the generated bytecode is significantly larger compared to what I found on Etherscan and includes the timestamp opcode.
When analyzing the bytecode generated locally, I divide it into three sections following a guide (https://www.rareskills.io/post/ethereum-contract-creation-code), which includes init code up to the fe opcode, runtime code up to the next fe opcode, and metadata in the final section.
Given this, my question is: should I trust the “deployed bytecode” from Etherscan for an in-depth analysis, or is it better to compile the contract locally using SOLC and analyze that bytecode instead?

Are you using the same solc version? Did you compile with the same parameters? Ethereum page have links for several tools that can be used to verify deployed contracts if you have the source code, compilation settings and deployment parameters. https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/smart-contracts/verifying/

You are finding all these differences between code and deployed bytecode because you are looking at a proxy.
The deployed bytecode is the one of the proxy, which is quite small since its only job is to delegate the call to the implementation (or change the implementation).
The code etherscan shows you contains both the proxy and the implementation. Generally it can contain even contracts that don't get even deployed.
The creation bytecode contains also the implementation because, if you look at the constructor of the proxy, it deploys the implementation in the same transaction.
